# Angular CLI error when running project, module not found Cant resolve 'AngularProjectPath' in 'AngularProjectPath'

Tags: angular, typescript

As title says, i'm not able to compile my angular project since it's not able to resolve my working directory:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'D:\Proyectos\Yesoft\newschool\angularFront' in
> 'D:\Proyectos\Yesoft\newschool\angularFront'

Any ideas where to start? it was compiling a moment ago and now it's just failing

Comment: Weird. Maybe just do a reboot first..

Comment: already did, tried the basics, reboot, copy to another location (not working), compile a new project (it works), verify lazy chunk files for an error (nothing), thats the complete error i see nothing else, double check chrome console and nothing

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing this error, i found the solution, since there is no other exception other than your working directory showing on the error, go and verify your configuration files (angular.json,polyfills.ts, main.ts).

I found an empty string ("") insde angular.json where the styles are loaded.

> "styles": ["src/styles.css",""
> ],

It was added by vscode prettier extension which caused this issue, since it's a valid compiler string it makes no greater issue other than failing to find the file (and that is why the error points to the working directory).

I hope someone finds this useful.